# How can i get my menu with password checker and write to file program working

Tags: python, function

Whenever I enter the password it keeps asking for a capital letter even when I enter it here is my code I think the function of checking the capital, numbers and length is not correct

```
import string
caps = string.ascii_uppercase
lowercase = string.ascii_lowercase
numbers = []
for i in range(10):
    numbers.append(str(i))



def caps_found_pass(pw):
    found = False
    for letter in caps:
        if pw.find(letter) > -1:
            found= True
        return found

def lowercase_found_pass(pw):
    found = False
    for letter in lowercase:
        if pw.find(letter) > -1:
            found= True
        return found

def number_found_pass(pw):
    found = False
    for number in numbers:
        if pw.find(number) > -1:
            found = True
        return found


def register ():
 user_names_add = input ("Enter your first name and last name: ")
 c = user_names_add.split ()
 initial=c[0] [0]
 lastname_initial=c [1] [0]
 user_dob_add = input("Enter your Date Of Birth in format DDMMYYYY  ")

 username = initial + lastname_initial + user_dob_add
 file = open("accounts.txt", "a")
 file.write(username)
 file.write(" ")
 file.close()
 print ("Your new username is ", username)
 while True:
        password = input("Please input your desired password: ")
      if caps_found_pass(password):
        if lowercase_found_pass(password):
            if number_found_pass(password):
                if len(password) > 6 and password < 15:
                    print(f'Your password is {password}')
                    pass
                else:
                    print("Password must contain at least 7 characters and no more than 14 ")
            else:
                print("Password must contain a number")
        else:
            print("Password must contain a lowercase letter")
      else:
        print("Password must contain a capital letter")


 file = open("accounts.txt")
 file.write(password)
 file.write("\n")
 file.close()

def login ():
     username = input("Please enter your username")
     password = input("Please enter your password")
     for line in open("accounts.txt","r").readlines():
        login_info = line.split()
        if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
            print("User and Pass correct logging in...")
            return True
        print("Incorrect User and/or pass.")
        return False

def test():
    open("accounts.txt")

def quit ():
    print ("quitting")

def invalid ():
    print ("invalid")

def user_menu ():
    print ()
    print("Menu")
    print("-------------")
    print()
    print("Select A Function")
    print("1. Login")
    print("2. Register")
    print("3. Testing/View all Users and Passwords")
    print("9. Quit")
    print()
    selection = input ("Type, 1,2,3 or 9 ")
    return selection

quit_program = False
while not quit_program:
    option = user_menu()
    if option == "1":
        login ()
    elif option == "2":
        register ()
    elif option == "3":
         test ()
    elif option == "9":
        quit_program = True
    else:
        invalid ()
```

I have tried to change my function of checking the capital, numbers and length of the code but to no avail I believe the menu is working fine I just need the password to work so I can see if it can write to file

Comment: Your **return** statements need to be outside of the for-loop in these functions: `caps_found_pass`, `lowercase_found_pass`, and `number_found_pass`

Comment: Also you need to update code to this : `if len(password) > 6 and len(password) < 15:`

Comment: I did all these suggestions and still the same